# I'm trying to print my array but i'm not getting my desired result

Tags: c++

I'm fairly new to programming and was trying to create a program which creates a one dimensional array with random numbers from a certain range and then prints it out. I managed to make a function to create the array but I'm having trouble actually printing out the array I made. I have a general idea of what the problem might be but no clue as to how to fix the code.

Here is the code in question:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int *create(int n)
{
    int *arr = new int [n];
    
    for (int i = 0; i > n; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = rand() % 100;
    }
}

int main ()
{
    int n = 12;
    int *arr = create(n);
    
    cout << "this is the array: ";
    
    for (int i = 0; i > n; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    };
    
    delete[] arr;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This condition `i > n` should be `i < n`, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two errors in your code:

1. You are not returning your array from `create()`
2. Your loop condition is incorrect.

Fixed code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int *create(int n)
{
    int *arr = new int [n];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = rand() % 100;
    }
    return arr;
}

int main ()
{
    int n = 12;
    int *arr = create(n);
    
    cout << "this is the array: ";
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    };
    
    delete[] arr;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I dont see how you code compiles.

1. You are not returning anything from function.
2. both your loop conditions should be `<n`

This way is works but your design is very poor, unless you are just learning handling pointers.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int* create(int n)
{
    int* arr = new int[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = rand() % 100;
    }
    return arr;
}

int main()
{
    int n = 12;
    int* arr = create(n);

    cout << "this is the array: ";

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    };

    delete[] arr;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only missing part in your code - you are not returning your arr variable from your create function.

```
int *create(int n)
{
    int *arr = new int [n];
    
    for (int i = 0; i > n; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = rand() % 100;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

This way it will work:)

Comment: @drescherjm I agree that it's wrong but I decided to leave this minor mistake for the topic starter to fix it on its own - this one is easy to notice and it occurs quite frequently. Thus I believe it is very important to see compiler output for this mistake at least once while you are studying:)

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake in the loop. you used '>' instead of '<' line 22 should be.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

The loop stopped before the first iterations because i=0 was smaller than n=12.